# What's the usage of rotating the screen 90 degrees in some laptops?

Tags: display-rotation

In some laptops like Lenevo, it's possible to rotate the screen 90 degrees by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>. How is this feature useful?

Comment: It could potentially be useful to display a printed page in portrait mode.  But more it's for external monitors and just a carry-over from other PC configurations, I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

It is used all the time!

Connect your laptop to an external monitor rotated 90deg and edit documents in portrait mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of the graphics chipet/driver, and was probably not intended specifically for the laptop screen per se. This *is* useful for use with flat screen panels that you can physically rotate 90 degrees on its stand, and I'm guessing they didn't care to disable the function just becaue you're using the internal screen.